# Как сделать кнопку закрытия в мобильном меню, за пределами блока?

Tags: css

На [сайте](https://forbss.ru) есть в мобильном меню "крестик", но хотелось бы вынести его отдельно за пределы блока, но не пойму как это реализовать, прошу помощи. Красным отметил где бы хотел его расположить.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97r7N.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Добавьте код меню в вопрос

Comment: Даже перейдя на ваш сайт невозможно открыть меню на мобильном, потому что js скрипты не работает

Comment: Контейнер мобильного меню (.mobile_menu_container) на вашем сайте имеет overflow:hidden, убирать которое не рекомендуется из-за механизмов отображения подменю. Таким образом размещенная снаружи кнопка закрытия меню будет скрыта, а у контейнера снизу появится ненужный горизонтальный скроллбар. Можно решить вопрос с помощью JS, но задумайтесь - действительно ли вам это нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Что то вроде: (CSS)

```
    .cross {
       position: relative;
       right: -75px;
    }
```

Таким образом мы перемещаем объект, но это не влияет на остальные элементы разметки.